# How to create an HtmlHelper extension method that will bind an IEnumerable<T> to a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-table, ienumerable, model-binding

This is my view model:

```
public class TaskViewModel{
  public int TaskID{get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<TaskExecutor> Executors{get;set;}
}

public class TaskExecutor{
  public int ExecutorID{get;set;}
  public string LastName{get;set;}
  public string FirstName{get;set;}
}
```

In my view I have done something like this:

```
<table>
 @foreach(var item in Model.Executors)
   {
      <tr>
         <td>item.ExecutorID</td>
         <td>@string.Format("{0} {1}",item.FirstName,item.LastName)</td>
      </tr>
   }
</table>
```

Now, when loading the view, there won't be any problem, but I might need to edit the table and I want the changes to persist when submitting the form. The only way I can think of is an HtmlHelper extension method that will properly bind an IEnumerable to a table but I have no idea how to do that. I'd be happy to see some code. Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I might need to edit the table and I want the changes to persist when submitting the form"? Are you talking about editing the values in the table and persisting those changes between subsequent requests?

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables)

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisPratt, I had internet issues. Yes, I mean that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you're as always very helpful. That article seems to do just what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be as follows:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class ExecutorsExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString Executors(this HtmlHelper helper, List<TaskExecutor> executors)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<table>");
            for (var i = 0; i < executors.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                sb.Append(string.Format("<td><input name=\"Executors[{0}].FirstName\" value=\"{1}\"></td>", i, executors[i].FirstName));

                // add other cells here                 
                sb.Append("<tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("</table>");

            return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
@Html.Executors(Model.Executors)
```

Please note you would need to make the Executors a `List<TaskExecutor>` for the indexing to work properly.

The indexing of the loop and and name variable would keep the model binding happy. You could add further fields where I have commented above.

You could also use `Html.TextBox` or `Html.TextBoxFor` to generate the inputs if needed.