# Checkbox is checked but Model is still false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, model-binding

I have the following model:

```
  public class TaskViewModel{
   //other properties are omitted for brevity
    public bool IsUnderControl{get;set;}
  }
```

On the other hand I have these two DOM elements that I manually bind to the model property:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="IsUnderControl" value="true"/>
<input type="hidden" name="IsUnderControl" value="false" />
```

Now, after submitting, the value of `IsUnderControl` is false even if the checkbox is checked. Here's the POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveTask(TaskViewModel tvm){
   //When I debug the code I see that tvm.IsUnderControl=false
   if (ModelState.IsValid){
     //I save the task to repository
  }
}
```

*Note: When I inspect the checkbox I see that there's no `checked="checked"` among the element checkbox atributes.

EDIT: Here's the javascript with which I create the corresponding input element:

```
$('#taskConfig').
   append('<input type="checkbox"  value="true" 
   name="IsUnderControl"/>').append('<input type="hidden" value="false"    
   name="IsUnderControl"/>');
```

Comment: Have you tried using a HTML Helper instead? `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsUnderControl)`

Comment: Is that `public bool IsUnderControl { get; set; }`? And what is the signature of the POST method?

Comment: I think you havn't bind model property with checkbox. Try using Html.Checkbox or Html.CheckboxFor.

Comment: Yes, @StephenMuecke, it's public. I've added the POST method as well

Comment: `checked="checked"` will only be set if you actually bind to your property using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsUnderControl)` and the value of `IsUnderControl` is `true`

Comment: I assume `IsUnderControl` is a bool?

Comment: I assume also that it is typeof `bool`.

Comment: The thing is I can't use @Html.CheckBoxFor because that check box is created with JavaScript. So, does that mean if I don't use that helper method, I won't get what I need?

Comment: Show the javascript. Only thing I can think of is that you have disabled the checkbox, or maybe it hasn't been added within the form tag.

Comment: I've added the javascript code. There's nowhere I disable the checkbox. And the `taskConfig`, which is a `div`, is inside the form tag.

Comment: I have tested you code and it works fine. There must be something else causing it to post back `false`. Is there any other javascript?

Comment: Out of curiosity, since its a model property, why not use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsUnderControl)` and make full use of strongly typed model binding? If you want it to be initially 'hidden', you could always put it inside a hidden element and use jquery to show it.

Comment: Ok, @Stephen, first of all, thank you tons for paying so much attention on this issue. Second, in fact I just presented a model that is a bit different from the original one. In fact, it's not a direct property of the model, the model has a property called Task, which has a property List<Executors>. And the Executor has a property called IsUnderControl. The list of executors are populated by the user input, so I can't decide beforehand. Thus the name of the checkbox is "Task.Executors[i].IsUnderControl", not "IsUnderControl"

Comment: This has a relationship with a question I've asked before where you also made a comment. Here's the SO thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237650/how-to-create-an-htmlhelper-extension-method-that-will-bind-an-ienumerablet-to

Comment: Collections will only bind if the indexers starts at zero and are consecutive. My best guess is that they are not, so binding fails and `IsUnderControl` is `false` because that's the default.

Comment: On the form I have three checboxes and 6 corresponding input fields (3 checkbox, 3 hidden). The names are like the following: `name="Task.Executor[0].IsunderControl",name="Task.Executor[1].IsunderControl",name="Task.Executor[2].IsunderControl"`. Is this OK? And JFYI, the collection does bind. I get 3 Executors, with other values set properly,except for the IsunderControl.

Comment: If the model is as per the other question i.e. `TaskViewModel` has property  `IEnumerable<TaskExecutor> Executors` and `TaskExecutor` has property  `IsunderControl` then you need to remove the `Task` prefix. It needs to be just `Executor[0].IsunderControl`

Comment: I've changed the model a bit after that question. Now `IEnumerable<TaskExecutor> ` is `List<Executor>` and it's not a direct property of `TaskViewModel`, It's `TaskViewMode.Task.List<Executor>`. Ok, from what I understand, there's nothing wrong I've done so far,(I know as far as the code I provided is concerned). I don't want to waste your time anymore. Will try to find that subtle detail and let you know of the result.

Comment: Looks OK then. Perhaps generate the all the controls in a `for` loop just for testing, edit some in the view, and check that it posts back correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to thank @Stephen Muecke for his help. His suggestions helped me opt out the possible mistakes and I finally found where my mistake was. I use Entity Framework and I haven't found a better way to wire a bool property to a column in Oracle database, than having another property called,say, `IsUnderControlInt` and converting to or from this property to boolean in the getters and setters methods. Like such:

```
[Column("ISUNDERCONTROL")]
public int IsUnderControlInt {get;set;}
[NotMapped]
public bool IsUnderControl 
{
   get {return Convert.ToBoolean(IsUnderControlInt);}
   set IsUnderControlInt=Convert.ToInt32(value);//This is correct
}
```

I had a mistake in the setter: Instead of converting the passed `value` to Int32, I was converting itself, like this:

```
 set IsUnderControlInt=Convert.ToInt32(IsunderControl);This is incorrect
```

That's why it never got set to true. Now it works great. Thank you all.